# Haskell - Recursion through list of lists?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do recursion over a list of lists in Haskell. Here's my issue:

```
type Symbol = String
type Sentence = [[Symbol]]

getSymbols :: [Sentence] -> [Symbol]
getSymbols [[]] = []
getSymbols ((sym:stmt):(stmts))
    | stmt == [] = getSymbols stmts
    | sym `elem` stmt = getSymbols ((stmt):(stmts))
    | otherwise = sym : getSymbols ((stmt):(stmts))
```

I'm trying to return a list of all symbols found in a given sentence with no duplicates present e.g.

```
getSymbols [["A","B","C"],["D","A"],["E","B","C"]]
```

would return:

```
["A","B","C","D","E"] --order does not matter--
```

I've been trying a few different ways but just can't seem to get it - I'm still fairly raw at Haskell so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You could maybe try to decompose the problem into easier subproblems? E.g. create a big list with everything in it first and then remove duplicates. The answer to your question would then be to compose these simpler functions.

Comment: @gallais Would that need me to write more functions or can it still be done in a single function? Because I'm wanting to solve the problem with just a single function

Comment: @willrobertshaw i don't think it is a good idea. Functional programming is in its core about composing functions. The earlier you get used to writing small composable functions the better. Think what is more versatile small Lego bricks or a toy car?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import Data.List
nub . concat $ [["A","B","C"],["D","A"],["E","B","C"]]
```

Comment: Would you add some explanation, obviously the OP is not interested in the result but the how and why

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getSymbols          []  = []
getSymbols (   [] :xss) = getSymbols xss
getSymbols ((x:xs):xss)
    | x `elem` (getSymbols (xs:xss)) =      getSymbols (xs:xss)
    | otherwise                      = x : (getSymbols (xs:xss))
```

Comment: Hi - I tried this but I get a type error on the last line "Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
    Expected type: Symbol
      Actual type: [Symbol]
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘sym’
    In the expression: sym : (getSymbols (stmt : stmts))" Any help?

Answer (score 0):

> @gallais Would that need me to write more functions or can it still be
>   done in a single function? Because I'm wanting to solve the problem
>   with just a single function

It is wise to want simple solutions but reducing the number of functions you use is not how you achieve this goal with Haskell. Instead, to find simple solutions you want to reuse definitions. You want to see the solution to your problem as a composition of known solutions to smaller problems. This lets you solve many things by only remembering a little.

So, we start with a list like this:

```
[["A","B","C"],["D","A"],["E","B","C"]]
```

And we want to find a list that contains all the same strings and no others and no duplicates. What if we flatten the list with `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`?

```
["A","B","C","D","A","E","B","C"]
```

Given the same problem statement it is clear that we're going to come to the same answer. All that is important is what strings are present; the rest of the structure is irrelevant.

From this point we just need to remove the duplicates in the list. There are several ways to do this. An inefficient one is `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`. A more efficient method is `Set.toList . Set.fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` with `import qualified Data.Set as Set`. Whatever we choose, our solution looks like:

```
nub . concat
```

Bonus: devise a method to remove duplicates that uses `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` from `Data.List`.